# What is the "sin" referred to in Hebrews 11:25?

Tags: greek, word-study, hebrews, authorial-intent

> [Hebrews 11:25](https://biblehub.com/hebrews/11-25.htm) choosing rather to be mistreated with the people of
>   God than to enjoy the fleeting pleasures of **sin**.

What is the **sin** referred to here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throughout history, there have been some Jews (Israelites, etc.) who have abandoned their people in the face of persecution by foreign powers. Hence, it seems the author refers to the sin of apostasy. Rather than apostatize and enjoy the pleasures that such a sin provided, Moses chose to endure affliction with his people of Israel.